# Sometimes AVPlayer stalling and seekToTime: not respondin

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I'm playing youtube videos using AVPlayer as follows,

```
    - (void)startYoutubeVideoAtUrl:(NSURL *)videoUrl
{
    NSLog(@"start player at url : %@", videoUrl);

    [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:videoUrl completeBlock:^(NSDictionary *videoDictionary, NSError *error) {
        if (videoDictionary && videoDictionary.count > 0) {
            NSString *URLString = [self chooseYoutubeUrlFromUrlList:videoDictionary];

            AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self videoURLWithCustomScheme:@"streaming" uRLString:URLString] options:nil];

            [asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)];

            pendingRequests = [NSMutableArray array];

            avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

            [self startVideoPlayBack];
        }
        else {
            [_delegate failedStartPalyInlineVideo];
        }
    }];
    }


-(void)startVideoPlayBack
{
    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    avPlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
    avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
    [avPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
    [avPlayerLayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"readyForDisplay" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

    [self watchApiCall];
    avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[avPlayer currentItem]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemPlaybackStalled:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification
                                               object:[avPlayer currentItem]];


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    @try {
        if (!avPlayer) {
            return;
        }

        if (avPlayerItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {

        }
        else if (avPlayerItem.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"----- AVPlayerStatusFailed ----");
            [self playbackVideo];
        }

        if (object == avPlayerLayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"readyForDisplay"]) {
            [self resetNetworkSpeedUsingLoadingTime];

            if (avPlayerLayer.readyForDisplay) {
                id<LoopingVideoDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;

                if([strongDelegate readyForVideoDisplay]) {
                    [avPlayer play];
                }
                else {
                    [self removePlayer];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @catch(NSException *ex) {
        NSLog(@"EXCEPTION : %@", ex);
    }
}
```

My issue is some times the video getting stalled and fires `AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification`. Also it's not responding `[avPlayerItem seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];` sometimes after called `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` selector. I wasn't able to find a solution for this. I checked with,

```
[HCYoutubeParser thumbnailForYoutubeURL:videoUrl thumbnailSize:YouTubeThumbnailDefaultHighQuality completeBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:videoUrl completeBlock:^(NSDictionary *videoDictionary, NSError *error) {
            NSString *URLString = [self chooseYoutubeUrlFromUrlList:videoDictionary];

            NSURL *urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

            avPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:urlToLoad];
            [self startVideoPlayBack];
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error in youtube parser");
    }
}];
```

and there is no any player stall issue or `seekToTime:` not responding issue with that. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Observe your `AVPlayerItem's` `loadedTimeRanges` and `seekableTimeRanges` property to make make sure that the `AVPlayer` has loaded playable data yet. When steaming, the `AVPlayer` often pause falling short of playable(data that can be played by `AVPlayer`) data. This should help investigate further into the issue. You can also try to start playback when you get `avPlayerItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` by calling `play` on your `AVPlayer`

From AV Foundation Programming Guide

> Monitoring Playback
>
> You can monitor a number of aspects of both the presentation state of a player and the player item being played. This is particularly useful for state changes that are not under your direct control. For example:
>
> - If the user uses multitasking to switch to a different application, a player’s rate property will drop to 0.0.
> - If you are playing remote media, a player item’s loadedTimeRanges and seekableTimeRanges properties will change as more data becomes available.
>
>   These properties tell you what portions of the player item’s timeline are available.
> - A player’s currentItem property changes as a player item is created for an HTTP live stream.
> - A player item’s tracks property may change while playing an HTTP live stream.
>     This may happen if the stream offers different encodings for the content; the tracks change if the player switches to a different encoding.
> - A player or player item’s status property may change if playback fails for some reason.
>     You can use key-value observing to monitor changes to values of these properties.